# Password doesn't get updated for user in rails after reseting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I previously had a page as settings to update the user details in rails. On that time the password gets updated without any issue. But now I used a password reset option for the users who forgot their password. They will receive a mail and then they reset the password. After adding this feature both the updating inside the account and via mail does not happen.

password_reset controller:

```
def update

  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hour.ago
    flash[:notice] = 'Password reset has expired'

    redirect_to new_password_reset_path

  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])// this condition fails. I don't know why it fails.

    flash[:notice] = 'Password has been reset!'
    redirect_to new_session_path
  else
   redirect_to new_session_path
  end
```

user.rb

```
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 } 
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true 
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token


  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def generate_token(column)
      begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
    end
```

These filters I used in user controller

```
 before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :requestuser]
 before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
 before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy
```

I am new to rails and learning. Need help. The same filter I used before password reset I dont know why it fails. It first worked for few days now it fails.

Comment: Your comments in code says "this conditions fails". Please show the stack trace with error.

Comment: You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails-3`. Do you really use Rails 3.x which reached end-of-life more than three years ago?

Answer (score 1):

You write conditional but I think that your second conditional is not setup correctly, respectively the elsif in your case does not contain any conditional.

The correct syntax for the if statement is

```
if conditional
   code
elsif conditional
   code
else
   code
end
```

**Conditionals are a combination of if statements and comparison operators (<, >, <=, >=, ==, !=, &&, ||).**

If if you keep the conditional in mind and re-visit your code, there is a conditional missing, I'd expect something like, look at if and elsif, I have exchanged the > and < operators as it makes more sense to me.

```
@user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
if @user.password_reset_sent_at > 2.hour.ago
  # your if action here ...

elsif @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hour.ago
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

else
  # your else action ...
end
```

To know what's going on in case of silent errors or just a false return value when using `update_attributes` I suggest to use `update_attributes!(attributes)`, at least for testing / debugging. This method also updates an object just like Base.update_attributes but calls save! instead of save so an exception is raised if the record is invalid and you can see what's going wrong.

You could also use a rails console by typing `rails c` in a terminal and test `@user.update_attributes('any_value')` in there.

Comment: This is roughly what I was just typing up, I think this is good advice.  In addition to this, it's also possible to assign the password without using the update_attributes method and that is something to try.  It would look kind of like this ```@user.password = params[:user][:password]``` and then ```if @user.save``` do something under that.

Comment: @user.save fails I dont know why

Comment: Have you fixed the conditional or was it just a typo in your question? Try `user.save!` to raise an error if it fails. The same works with `update_attributes!(attributes)`, this also updates an object just like Base.update_attributes but calls save! instead of save so an exception is raised if the record is invalid.

Comment: Updated my answer.